# Progress bar sizing Android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I am looking for a way to make a progress bar fill effect on Android.
I have a `FrameLayout` called `progressBar` and inside this `FrameLayout` is a `LinearLayout` called `filledBar`. I don't know the literal widths of either `progressBar` or `filledBar`, but I would like `filledBar` to take up a certain amount of `progressBar`. How would I do this? (I am creating both bars programatically)

Comment: why don't you use the progressBar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html ?

Comment: @Budius I am looking to be able to add text to it and style it more independently

Comment: from my experience it probably would be easier to create a custom drawable and use it as a view background.

Comment: @Budius I want it to look like this: http://i.imgur.com/mHN3xxU.png

The progress bar as a whole should have a width of MATCH_PARENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite simple, do a XML layout like this:

```
FrameLayout
    View // background set to be a custom drawable
    TextView // gravity right
```

in code you inflate it and set the drawable:

```
private CustomDrawable drawable;

drawable = new CustomDrawable(context);
View v = layout.findViewById(...
v.setBackground(drawable);
```

then to update the percentage

```
drawable.setLevel(10);  // for 10% for example
```

when you create your custom drawble inside the draw method it's a simple call to drawRect

```
{

canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getLevel()/100*canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight, paint);

}
```

the `paint` you create with the color you want it to be.

That's a very rough idea, but I hope it's enough to guide you to the correct direction.

Comment: I can't manage to get this working. The canvas doesn't seem to draw.